# Copy GridView to Another GridView on client (also ListViews)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, listview, gridview

I have a project where I am collecting information on multiple tabs in an ASP.net web application.  I am using the Microsoft AJAX toolkit to support the tabs.  Once the information is collected, I have included a "Review" tab which summarizes the information on the other tabs.

I started by using an UpdatePanel, but I found that it processing took far too long, on the order of 5-10 seconds when hosted on my development workstation and on our web server.

I moved to using straight Javascript on the client side to copy the data from the three other tabs to the Review tab with success when handling text boxes and drop down lists.  However, I have one GridView containing text data and one ListView containing photos which need to be copied to the review panel.

I have been unsuccessful in copying the data to new controls which I added to hold the data.  When saving the record, I am extracting the data from the original tabs (which is working well), so I don't need the GridView and ListView on the Review panels to be functional, from a data access perspective; the controls just need to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

1 step- encapsulate your areas that you need to copy in a div.

2 step- create a function to extract the html of those div and pasting to the destination like

```
function printDiv(sourcediv,destinationdiv) {
document.getElementById(destinationdiv).innerHTML== document.getElementById(sourcediv).innerHTML;
 }
```